# How to set a fixed width for CheckboxModel column in GridPanel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I needed checkbox selection mode in my gridpanel, so i use `Ext.selection.CheckboxModel` component, but my problem is about the column (checkbox column) which this component will append to my grid. I want to set a fixed width for it, because this column's width may vary when i resize the browser window. I use the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
constructor: function() {
    var me = this;
        me.selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {width: 16});
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

This is code snippet and snapshot of my users table:

```
Ext.define('VDOA.view.users.Table', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
    alias: 'widget.usersgrid',
    forceFit: true,
    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    //selType: 'rowmodel',
    //selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
    title: '',
    initComponent: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

[image: snapshot of my panel]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in Ext 4.0.7:

It's the `forceFit: true` that screws up. They suggest to set `flex:1` on the remaining columns. That worked for me but I would still like to see it smaller. I'll probably go for a css solution.

[thread on the sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179657-CheckboxModel-does-not-play-nice-with-forceFit-and-rowEditing-please-help!)

Comment: +1 because `forceFit: true` got me, too. It's entirely non-obvious to me (new to ExtJS) that `forceFit` would stretch this column. Also, for the poster's actual problem, I think this should be the selected solution since he comments that all the other solutions didn't work for him.

Comment: Also note that if you have `flex: 1` in `defaults` of your columns it will affect the checkbox column too. You need to remove the `flex: 1` from `defaults` and move it to each definition of standard columns.

Answer (score 4):

You should use combination of:

1. Set flex property to each column as VDP proposed
2. Define `selModel` with `headerWidth` as Rich Waters proposed

Having this combination you will be able to control exact width of cell with checkbox

Answer (score 3):

There's an undocumented property that controls the column width, give this a shot:

```
selModel: {
    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    headerWidth: 16
}
```

Comment: i used this property but still no luck :(

Comment: @AramAlipoor If this didn't work for you, do you mind accepting (or creating if it doesn't exist) an answer that did work for you?

Comment: actually i couldn't find a way around it and i just gave up.

Comment: `selModel : Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',{headerWidth:40})` worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating things. Just add this line into your grid panel definition:

```
selType: 'checkboxmodel'
```

And you will get nice, fixed width, non resizable checkbox column in the front.

Comment: I used what you said, but it not fixed-width yet.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Because it absolutely fixed width in my samples.

Comment: Hm... What version of ExtJs you're using? And the screen shot you posted, is it after grid is rendered? Or after you resized first column?

Comment: i'm using extjs 4.0.x and this screen shot is right after grid render. and to mention i cannot resize first column.

Comment: So it's not resizable. Just strange width?

Comment: yes and as i resize the browser, the column's width will change too.

Comment: Do you have any column with 'flex' property?

Comment: yeah all of my other columns have flex property.

Answer (score 0):

You try to put every thing inside the "initComponent function" .

```
initComponent: function () {
    this.items = [{
       //define grid view 
       selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
       }
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```